# box-shadow inset on img doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have given `box-shadow` to image

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px RED inset
```

but the shadow is not appearing on image, if i change path of image by using firebug then i can see that shadow is in the back side of image.

**I want to give shadow on the image**, Please help

[image]

Comment: try removing `inset`.

Comment: i want to give shadow inside of image,

Comment: The inset shadow actually renders behind the image, something I've had issues with in the past.

Comment: `box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ff0000;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution 1

Use CSS Positioning techniques to achieve that.... Here, first of all am wrapping the image in a `div` element and later am using CSS pseudo `:after` element which is positioned absolute with an *inset* `box-shadow`

Now make sure you've set the container element, in this case it's a `div` element to `position: relative;` else your shadow will fly out in the wild.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xev7/)</kbd>

```
div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1; /* You can use higher to ensure that it stays on top */
}
```

I forgot to use the `z-index` property so use it for the `absolute` positioned pseudo to ensure that it stays on the top always...

Also, would like to make a note here that if you want the `div` to be side by side, you will need `float` or `display: inline-block;` as `div` elements are *block* in nature and will take 100% of the document `width`...

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xev7/1/)</kbd> *(`z-index` included in this demo)*

---

### Solution 2

If for some reason you want to ignore the use of `:after` pseudo *(I don't see any reason of doing that as it's supported on IE8 as well)* so you can also use a negative `z-index` on the `img` element, and use the `box-shadow` with `inset` value on the `div` element.

```
div {
    position: relative; /* Not required now */
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

div img {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xev7/2/)</kbd> *(Just playing with the `z-index` property)*

Comment: Full Specification here -  http://designbystevie.com/2011/03/applying-css3-inset-box-shadows-to-images/